# web.xml in war getting misplaced using gradle

Tags: jakarta-ee, gradle

My `build.gradle` looks somewhat like this. Its so clear that my `web.xml` is in `WebContent/WEB-INF`, then why does the war get created with `web.xml` under `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib` folder ?

I inflated the war, and got this

> inflating: WEB-INF/lib/web.xml

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'
    compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat', name: 'tomcat-catalina', version: '8.5.0'
    compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.16'

    compile files('WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/coregeneral.jar')
    compile files('WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/operationserverendpoints.jar')

    compile files('WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had added `web.xml` as a compile option, that was incorrect. I removed it from the compile option and added this, it worked.

```
war {
webXml = file('WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml') // copies a file to WEB-INF/web.xml
}
```